# How to loop back to the beginning in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I need a bit of help in finishing this code. I am stuck trying to figure out what's wrong with my code. I don't know how to loop back from the top using while loop. It also wont print the last bit. I got the prime numbers settled but I don't know how the looping back works. May you help me?

```
while True:
    num=int(input("Enter a number:"))
    no="n"
    yes="y"
    
    if num >=1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                print(num,"is not a prime number")
                break
        else:
            print(num,"is a prime number")  
    x=str(input("If you want to continue press y, n if not:"))

if x==yes:
    print()
    #this part I don't know how to loop back to the start

elif x==no:        
        print("Okay")
    #and also the loop won't stop and print the text up there^^^ when I choose n
```

Comment: The `while` structure automatically loops back at the end of its indented block. Simply push your `if` (along with everything below it) four spaces in and it will be included into the loop.

Comment: Your loop body has to contain everything that should "loop back".  `if x==yes` is outside of the loop, so it only executes after you have exited your `while True` loop.

Comment: Small unrelated hint: You don't have to call `str` on the return value of `input` as you did in `x=str(input("If you want to continue press y, n if not:"))`. The return value from `input` is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

put the if in the while loop only, and break out of the while loop if no

```
while True:
    ...
    x=str(input("If you want to continue press y, n if not:"))

    if x=="no":        
        print("Okay")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to repeat infinitely, your code structure might look like this:

```py
while True:  # The outer while loop, only ends when the player says "n"
    while True:
        # This is where you get the prime nums, paste the code for that here
    if x == "n":
        break  # This method will only stop the loop if the input is "no", else it keeps looping forever
```

Or, more simply, you can do this in just one loop. The structure would be like this:

```py
while True:
    # Get if the num is prime, paste the code for that

    if x == "n":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution if the following:

```
def is_prime(num):
    if num <= 1:
        return False
    if num % 2 == 0:
        return num == 2
    d = 3
    while d * d <= num and num % d != 0:
        d += 2
    return d * d > num
        

while True:
    num=int(input("Enter a number: "))
    
    if is_prime(num):
        print(f'{num} is a prime number')
    else:
        print(f'{num} is not a prime number')
        
    x = str(input("If you want to continue enter Y, or N if not: ")).lower()

    if x == 'y':
        print("let's start over...\n")

    elif x == 'n':      
        print("Okay, see you")
        break
```

Returns:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this. In my opinion function more usefull for check prime numbers.

```
def is_prime(x):
    for d in range(2, int(x**0.5)+1):
        if x % d == 0:
            return False
    return x > 1

no, yes = "n", "y"
x = yes
while x == yes:
    num=int(input("Enter a number:"))
    
    if is_prime(num):
        print(num,"is a prime number")
    else:
        print(num,"is not a prime number")

    x = input("If you want to continue press y, n if not:")

print("Okay")
```